# How to translate windowmanager floating layout diagonally with animation? (ChatHead click animation)

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-windowmanager, android-transitions

I'm trying to implement chatheads in my application. I've managed to get everything working, onClick the custom layout opens which is a relative layout with a webview and some buttons. The chathead moves to the top right corner when its clicked simultaneously opening the defined layout. 
Now the only problem I'm facing is the chathead translation, when moving it to the top right corner it doesn't transit smoothly as I've not given any animations to it and I don't know how. 
I searched for a mwthod and found the ValueAnimator which I tried using.

```
        private ValueAnimator mMoveEdgeAnimator;


        mParams.y = goalPositionY;

        mMoveEdgeAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentX, goalPositionX);
        mMoveEdgeAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                mParams.x = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(FloatingView.this, mParams);
            }
        });

        mMoveEdgeAnimator.setDuration(MOVE_TO_EDGE_DURATION);
        mMoveEdgeAnimator.setInterpolator(mMoveEdgeInterpolator);
        mMoveEdgeAnimator.start();
```

But it only works for one of the axis either X or Y which doesn't look seamless on screen, I want it to translate diagonally similar to how facebook chathead reacts onClick.

How can I translate it diagonally? Also how can I apply a grow animation on windowManager.addView()?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Property Value Holders to animate across x an y.

```
public void animate(final View v, int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY) {

    PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("x", startX, endX);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("y", startY, endY);

    ValueAnimator translator = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(pvhX, pvhY);

    translator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.x = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x");
            layoutParams.y = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y");
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, layoutParams);
        }
    });

    translator.setDuration(100);
    translator.start();
}
```